# Getting a 404 error while trying to connect backend Api from the Heroku deployed Angular Api

Tags: node.js, angular, api, heroku, backend

I have successfully deployed my angular app onto Heroku. I have implemented the proxy.conf.json file to connect to the Backend API (which is also deployed in Heroku and its a Java JAX-RS REST API) and it is  up and running.
The `proxy.conf.json` file contains:

```
{
"/webapi/*": {
  "target": "https://backend-api.herokuapp.com",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true
}  }
```

Also updated the `start` command in the package.json file as

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
```

This is working perfectly fine in local using `localhost:4200`
But when I am deploying the project onto heroku, the backend call is not being held.
for your reference i am attaching the complete `package.json`file

```
    {
  "name": "myapp-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run build & concurrently --kill-others \"npm run serve-api\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "serve": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "serve-api": "node server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.8.0",
    "npm": "6.14.7"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.6",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.9",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.6",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.54",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 9.1.9.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/myapp_tool/myapp-client.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/myapp_tool/myapp-client/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/myapp_tool/myapp-client#readme"
}
```

And the `server.js` file contains:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://backend-api.herokuapp.com',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

//app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/myapp-client')));

//app.use('/webapi',api);
app.get('/webapi', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for Java API!'})
});

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/myapp-client/index.html'));});
//app.get('*', function (req,res) {
        //res.sendFile('index.html', {root: '/dist/myapp-client'}));});
//const port = process.env.PORT || '8080';
//app.set('port',port);

//const server = http.createServer(app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function (){
    console.log('CORS-enabled API is running on Port:${process.env.PORT || 8080}')
});
```

The deployed angular app works fine till its having static pages. but when it needs to access the backend-api it is unable to do so.
**Like when I want to login and send the userid and password; the request should go like following:**

```
https://myapp-client.herokuapp.com/login ==>> https://backend-api.herokuapp.com/webapi/login
```

***But in the browser console i found that it is actually sending request to:***

```
https://myapp-client.herokuapp.com/webapi/login
```

The angular app is unable to read the backend-api address; instead adds the rest of the path with it self(can't figure out why????).

I am unable to find any other method apart from proxy.conf.json and cors for dynamic backend api call.
Sorry guys for the long post. But i am unable to find any helpful material from anymore, hence I have explained all the things in more detail. Can anyone please help, I have a deadline hanging on me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding path rewrite property in your proxy configuration like this -

```
{
  context: '/webapi',
  pathRewrite: { '^/webapi': '' },
  target: "https://backend-api.herokuapp.com",
  secure: false,
  logLevel: "debug",
  changeOrigin: true
 }
```

Hope this might help!

Comment: sorry to say this isn't working. After the Host part, /webapi is the starting of the rest of the part of the URI of backend call. like when i hit 'https://myapp-client.herokuapp.com/analyzeProduct?productId=123', then the angular app should call the backend api as  'https://backend-api.herokuapp.com/webapi/analyzeProduct?productId=123&userName=XYZ'. its failed to call the backend-api altogether. Any more suggestions how i can have a backend call from the angular app

Comment: @SumitraOjha Can you create a plunker or stackblitz so i can look into the code. There are multiple ways to solve this if you are using any http interceptor then also you can alter the calls i mean you can add '/webapi' before. Using proxy configration is another way.

Comment: how can i implement this using http interceptor? can you please give me some insights so that i can understand the concept and work on this. thanks in advance